# Yielding multiple starting point requests with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working with the following code ( simplified):

```
def parse(self, response):

    print('hello')
    for x in xrange(8): 
        print x

        random_form_page = session.query(....


        PR = Request(
            'htp://my-api',
            headers=self.headers,
            meta={'newrequest': Request(random_form_page,  headers=self.headers)},
            callback=self.parse_PR
        )
        yield PR
```

I want to loop through a db table and grab the starting page for each scrape (random_form_page), then yield a request for each start page. In my code I can see that although it loops through 8 times it only yields a request for the first start page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`start_requests()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) instead of `parse()`:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for x in xrange(8): 
        random_form_page = session.query(....

        PR = Request(
            'htp://my-api',
            headers=self.headers,
            meta={'newrequest': Request(random_form_page,  headers=self.headers)},
            callback=self.parse_PR
        )
        yield PR
```

You should also omit `start_urls` if it is set.